# Loading text file into listbox. lines of code need to be Split

Tags: c#

Im trying to use the openfiledialog to load a text file.
string  string             bool
Name, year in highschool, failing?
code in text file

```
Chris | Junior | False
Jake Peters | Freshman | True
Jasmine Baker | Senior | False
```

So i use an array to take the code. then create a foreach loop to add to a string list

then split the line by " | " using a for loop

Then create a new object 
    and save the data using variables of the object.

Finally add to list box

converting isnt needed. you can ignore the bool. I would like to understand the concept more

What I meantioned was the method I tried. Did not load at all.

```
string[] b = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

List<string> ...
foreach(var a in b)
{
   list.Add(a);
}

for (int i =0; i<students.Count; i++)
{
list[i].Split('|');

//Human object...

Human x = new Human();

x.name =
listbox.add(x);
failinglistbox.Items.Add(x);
```

Comment: Well you are not showing all of your code e.g. `students` is not shown but just used. Anyhow, use `var parts = list[i].Split('|'); x.name = parts[0]; // and so on` because split gives an array.

Comment: Also, I suggest you use `foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(file path))` is better because it will read one line at a time on demand.

Comment: students is a the list

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you wanted.

```
string[] students = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

for (int i = 0; i < students.Length; i++)
{
    string[] cells = students[i].Split('|');

    //Human object...

    Human x = new Human();

    x.name =cells[0].Trim();

////////edited////////////
        x.year =cells[1].Trim();
        x.failing =cells[2].Trim();

    listbox.add(x);
    failinglistbox.Items.Add(x);
}
```

Comment: that makes everything the name. i need somthing that can split where listbox will take an object human with a name, a year and failing?